# Django Template: Use translation in default_if_none

Tags: python, django

How can I use a translated string inside a template for `default_if_none`?
Usually you would use something like this: `{% trans 'TRANSLATED STRING' %}`

**Example**

```
{{ value|default_if_none:'TRANSLATED STRING' }}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can store the translated string in a variable, like:

```
{% trans 'TRANSLATED STRING' as transl %}
{{ value|default_if_none:transl }}
```

It however might make sense to define a [custom template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/) here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Works like a charm. I also thought of a custom template filter. But for me it's quite odd that there is no out of the box solution.